# Multiple 302 redirct requests observed in nginx log no loop

Tags: php, nginx

My system receives traffic from users in the form of a 302 redirect.  I am observing multiple requests in the access.log for the same IP, same exact useragent, same time.  We are trying to figure out if this is an issue on my end or theirs.

My question is, what possible misconfiguration of nginx or php5-fpm could result in this happening on my server?  My nginx config is very basic, nothing fancy.

This usually occurs around 21 times per incident leading me to believe that it is the user's browser who is killing some kind of redirect loop.

```
95.90.x.x - - [18/Aug/2015:14:29:59 -0400] "GET /route.php?iid=ok3vn1j9662dewr0 HTTP/1.1" 302 15 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"                                                      
95.90.x.x - - [18/Aug/2015:14:29:59 -0400] "GET /route.php?iid=ok3vn1j9662dewr0 HTTP/1.1" 302 15 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"                                                      
95.90.x.x - - [18/Aug/2015:14:29:59 -0400] "GET /route.php?iid=ok3vn1j9662dewr0 HTTP/1.1" 302 15 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"                                                      
95.90.x.x - - [18/Aug/2015:14:30:00 -0400] "GET /route.php?iid=ok3vn1j9662dewr0 HTTP/1.1" 302 15 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"
```

Comment: the 302 redirect is the response your server is sending back to the user when they request the page `/route.php?iid=ok3vn1j9662dewr0`. It is likely just php, specifically `route.php` that is doing the redirect and issuing a `header("Location: /someOtherPage")` or a rewrite of a url that is redirecting them.

Comment: Yes it is route.php that does a Header("location... but it only happens once.  Are you saying that the route.php is the culprit and is replying more than one time?

Comment: It would depend on where route.php is redirecting. Very likely that it is redirecting to another url that resolves to route.php through a rewrite rule which redirects...etc.